# Swift - Instance member cannot be used on type custom class

Tags: ios, swift

I have no idea why I cannot call token on this argument, I keep getting error on this line

```
.ExtraHeaders(["Authorization": token])
```

The error

> Instance member 'token' cannot be used on type 'SocketIOManager'

Full code

```
import SocketIOClientSwift
import KeychainAccess

class SocketIOManager: NSObject {
    static let sharedInstance = SocketIOManager()



    let keychain = Keychain(server: "https://testing.herokuapp.com", protocolType: .HTTPS)

    var token: String {
        get {
            return String(keychain["token"])
        }
    }


    let socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: NSURL(string: 
       "https://testing.herokuapp.com")!, 
       options: [.Log(true), .ExtraHeaders(["Authorization": token]) ])


    override init() {
        super.init()
    }


    func establishConnection() {
        socket.connect()
    }



    func closeConnection() {
        socket.disconnect()
    }


}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestions, It doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be distilled into a tiny bit of code:

```
class Test {
    let test = "test"
    let test2 = test + "2" // instance member 'test' cannot be used on type 'Test'
}
```

The problem is that when those fields are initialized, the object doesn't exist yet. There are two ways of dealing with this:

```
 class Test {
    let test = "test"
    lazy var test2:String = self.test + "2" // since test2 is lazy, it only gets computed at a time when the object already exists
}
```

and

```
class Test {
    let test = "test"
    let test2:String

    init() {
        test2 = test + "2" // you can set constants in initializers
    }
}
```

The downside of the first option is that you have to use var, and you need to explicitly write `self`, the downside of the second is that your initializing code is not right where the declaration is. (though `init()` is a very logical place to look next) Both way require you to explicitly state the type. You have to decide what's more important to you, I'd opt for leaving constants constants when possible. But when you're using var already, might as well for the first option.

Note that if you choose the second option and your class inherits from another class, you need to initialize the member before calling `super.init()`:

```
class Test: SuperTest {
    let test = "test"
    let test2:String

    override init() {
        test2 = test + "2"
        super.init()
    }
}
```

The compiler will yell at you if you don't do this, so it's hard to get it wrong.

Comment: Im going with the first option but still received an error,  `lazy var socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: NSURL(string: "https://testing.herokuapp.com")!,
    options: [.Log(true), .ExtraHeaders(["Authorization": token]) ])`

Comment: I added lazy but for some reason, the current error keeps showing.

Comment: @airsoftFreak I've edited my answer, it should work now. Do consider the second option though, making a constant into a variable without good reason is not good practice in Swift.

Comment: I added self.token, but now the error is different, it is `SocketIOManager has no member token`

Comment: `Value of type 'NSObject -> () -> SocketIOManager has no member 'token'` is the full error

Comment: Don't mind this error. Solved it.

Comment: But i have another question, I tried your second option, received an error, because the token is a computed property, so i cant set it to `let`

Comment: second option will work if the token is a constant.